# How to find where the normal line of a curve cuts the x-axis and y-axis?

Tags: analytic-geometry, curves, tangent-line

> A line is drawn normal to the curve $y=\frac{2}{x^2}$ at the point on the curve where x=1. This line cuts the x-axis at P and the y-axis at Q. What is the length of PQ?

When $x=1$, $y=2$. I don't know how to find the points P and Q, but I know that for Q $x=0$ and for P $y=0$.

Comment: A line or the tangent line?

Comment: Actually, the normal line. I've read again the problem. Sorry, I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slope of the tangent is $y'= - \frac{4}{x^3} |_{x=1} = -4$

The equation of the tangent is $y-2 = -4(x-1) \implies y+4x = 6$

At the $x-$axis $y=0$ and at the $y-$ axis, $x=0$
From this find $P(a,0) \ , Q(0,b)$

The length will then be $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

---

**EDIT**: The slope the normal line is $m = - 1/y' = 1/4$

So, the equation of the normal line is 
$y-2 = \frac{1}{4}(x-1) \implies 4y - 8 = x - 1 \implies \color{red}{4y = x+7}$

The remaining part is the same.

Comment: Thank you so much! And sorry for the trouble. I understand now the problem thanks to you.

Answer (score 2):

First, we find the derivative of the function, by multiplying by the equation by the original exponent $-2$, and subtracting $1$ off the exponent.

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -4 \cdot x^{-3} = \frac{-4}{x^3}$$

At the point on the curve where $x=1, y=2$, and $\frac{dy}{dx} = -4$. The slope of the tangent at this point is thus $-4$, hence the slope of the normal is $\frac{1}{4}$.

Hence the intercepts are at $(0,1.75)=Q$  and $(-7,0) = P$. This means that $PQ$ has a length of $\sqrt{7^2 + 1.75^2} \approx 7.22$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) next time.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\;y(1)=2$, $\;y'(1)=-\frac 4{x^3}\Bigl|_{x=1}=-4 $, so the equation of the tangent line at $(1,2)$ is
$$ y-2 = -4(x-1)\iff 4x+y = 6? $$
Now the standard equation of a straightline, given its $x$-intercept $(a,0)$ and its $y$-intercept $(0,b)$ is
$$\frac xa +\frac yb=1,$$
so rewriring the equation of the tangent line as
$$\frac{2x}3+\frac y 6=1$$
instantly yields
$$a=\frac 32,\quad b=6.$$
and thence the length $PQ$.